# Multicolored nodes using igraph and vertex.pie

Tags: r, pie-chart, igraph, graph-coloring

I'd like to create multicolored nodes. I'd like to stay with `igraph`. I already found the `vertex.shape.pie` option.

Here is some example data:

```
test_fun <- function(color1,color2,len){
  vec <- replicate(len,sample(c(color1,color2,NA),1))
  return(vec)
}

set.seed(50)
num_nodes<- 20
test_graph <- erdos.renyi.game(num_nodes, 1/6)
V(test_graph)$color_1 <- test_fun("darkgreen","blue",num_nodes)
V(test_graph)$color_2 <- test_fun("brown","blueviolet",num_nodes)
V(test_graph)$color_3 <- test_fun("red","green",num_nodes)
V(test_graph)$color_4 <- test_fun("red","green",num_nodes)
plot(test_graph, vertex.size=7)


>test_graph
IGRAPH U--- 20 28 -- Erdos renyi (gnp) graph
+ attr: name (g/c), type (g/c), loops (g/l), p (g/n), color_1 (v/c), color_2 (v/c), color_3 (v/c), color_4 (v/c)
```

As you can see I have introduced `NA`s when I used the `test_fun`. This is on purpose to resemble my data.

I now want the vertices to be pie charts using the `vertex.shape.pie` option. Each node should be colored according to the attribute colors in color_1, color_2, color_3 and color_4.
If no column for a node is `NA`, 4 colors are assigned,
If one column for a node is `NA`, 3 colors are assigned,
and so on.

Thank you for your help!

PS.:

Here is the igraph example from http://igraph.org/r/doc/vertex.shape.pie.html

```
g <- graph.ring(10)
values <- lapply(1:10, function(x) sample(1:10,3))
if (interactive()) {
  plot(g, vertex.shape="pie", vertex.pie=values,
       vertex.pie.color=list(heat.colors(5)),
       vertex.size=seq(10,30,length=10), vertex.label=NA)
}
```

But I was not able to apply this on my example

**EDIT**
changed the seed to 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertex.pie` requires a list of values/proportions that each color will have in the pie.
You need to convert your `color_*` variables to that.

To do so, you can first bind them together:

```
v<-cbind(V(test_graph)$color_1,V(test_graph)$color_2,V(test_graph)$color_3,V(test_graph)$color_4)
```

Then for each vertex, make a vector of 6 values (one for each color) containing 0 and 1, 1 if the node has that color, 0 if it doesn't.

```
colors<-c("darkgreen","blue","blueviolet","brown","red","green")
values<-apply(v,1,function(x){
  sapply(colors,function(y){ifelse(y %in% x,1,0)})
})
values<-as.list(as.data.frame(values))
```

You can then plot using the function you mentionned:

```
plot(test_graph, vertex.shape="pie", vertex.pie=values,
    vertex.pie.color=list(colors),
    vertex.size=seq(10,30,length=10))
```

I changed the `set.seed` to 50 because with 42 some vertexes get only `NAs` so they cannot be plotted...

The total code would be:

```
library(igraph)

test_fun <- function(color1,color2,len){
  vec <- replicate(len,sample(c(color1,color2,NA),1))
  return(vec)
}

set.seed(50)
num_nodes<- 20
test_graph <- erdos.renyi.game(num_nodes, 1/6)
V(test_graph)$color_1 <- test_fun("darkgreen","blue",num_nodes)
V(test_graph)$color_2 <- test_fun("brown","blueviolet",num_nodes)
V(test_graph)$color_3 <- test_fun("red","green",num_nodes)
V(test_graph)$color_4 <- test_fun("red","green",num_nodes)

colors<-c("darkgreen","blue","blueviolet","brown","red","green")

v<-cbind(V(test_graph)$color_1,V(test_graph)$color_2,V(test_graph)$color_3,V(test_graph)$color_4)
values<-apply(v,1,function(x){
  sapply(colors,function(y){ifelse(y %in% x,1,0)})
})
values<-as.list(as.data.frame(values)) 

plot(test_graph, vertex.shape="pie", vertex.pie=values,
     vertex.pie.color=list(colors),
     vertex.size=seq(10,30,length=10))
```